# Regex Split: Split column into Name, percentage andsolvent

Tags: regex

Looking for a regex that can split expressions like:

> A-6-b 10/%XYZ

into:

> A-6-b
>   10%
>   /XYZ

Note that the first group can also contain spaces and numbers:

> AQDF 100 56%/ABC

and percentage can be a float:

> SFSDF 0.1%/ABC

I've come up with `(^[A-Z\s\d-]*)(?!%)(\d+%)(.*$)` but this doe snot match any percentages that are floats and more importantly even simple examples like `ABC 10%/XYZ` fail because the first digit of the percentage is assigned to the first capturing group.

Any idea how I can achieve what I want? I'm not a regex expert...

EDIT: fixed errors in example

EDIT2:

The examples are not complete. Here one more:

ABC Dwsd 0.01%/XYZ QST

- First part can contain spaces
- Last Part can contain spaces
- number can be a float

Comment: Isn't your use case just `make sure there is space before the last letters group`?

Answer (score 1):

Don't overcomplicate this by using one unreadable regex.

Based on what you've said, your separators are well defined (the last <kbd>space</kbd> and the last <kbd>%</kbd>). In JavaScript, for example, you could use:

```
var str = "A-6-b 10/%XYZ";

var firstSeparator = str.lastIndexOf(' ');
var secondSeparator = str.lastIndexOf('%');

var name = str.substring(0, firstSeparator);
var percentage = str.substring(firstSeparator + 1, secondSeparator + 1); // we want to include the % separator in this one
var solvent = str.substring(secondSeparator + 1);

console.log(name, percentage, solvent);
```

Working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rL5uymhm/

(There may be a typo in your question, as your examples differ on where the `/` symbol appears. So the code may need tweaking. My point still stands – don't use a regex for the sake of it when there is a more readable alternative.)

**IF you really want to use a regex**, [`/^(.+ )([^%]+%)(.*)$/`](http://regex101.com/r/pY5cJ3/1) should work.

Comment: Sorry for incomplete examples. The First part can also contain a space.

Comment: @beginner_ I know – my answer accommodates that, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Super simple:

```
/^(.*) ([1-9][0-9]*(?:\.[0-9]+)?%)(.*)$/
```

The most easily identifiable item is your percentage, so the `([1-9][0-9]*(?:\.[0-9]+)?%)` part deals with finding that.

Then it's simply a case of getting everything before (excluding the final space) to get the name, and everything after to get the solvent.

Done.

Answer (score 0):

I try this Let me know if you have any problem in comment.

```
((?:(?!\s*[0-9]*\/%).)*)\s*([\d\/%]*)\s*(.*)
```

**SEE DEMO :** http://regex101.com/r/lL8oN4/1

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me (using PCRE):

```
/^(.+) ([0-9.]+)[\/%]+([^\/]+)$/
```